PrimeNG p-tree: How to get infos of the integrated filter?
I have a PrimeNG p-tree element in an Angular webapp.
<p-tree #tree [value]="nodes" selectionMode="single" [filter]="filt" [contextMenu]="cm" [(selection)]="nodesel" scrollHeight="500px">

I have also a ViewChild to #tree.
@ViewChild ("tree") tree;

[filter] is set to true.
So I have this top input-fielt that - if there is an input - filters the showed elements with respect to that.
With
this.tree.resetFilter ();

I can reset this input-element. Its value is the empty and the filter resets - all elements are shown again.
Question: But how can I find out if there is a filter enabled (something in the input-field)
AND how can I start a re-filtering if the p-trees data changed??
